# Blast protection of doors and doorways

Tags: rust

So I was browsing the Rust Wiki and I noticed the amount of blasts needed per base item:

---

[Wooden doorway](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Doorway) : No blast amount stated.

---

[Wooden door](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Doorway) :

```
500HP

2HP per Rock - 250 Hits
1HP per Stone Hatchet - 500 Hits
2HP per Hatchet - 250 Hits
6HP per Pickaxe - 84 Hits
600HP per Explosive Charge Explosion - 1 Hits
```

---

[Metal doorway](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Doorway) : No blast amount stated.

---

[Metal door](http://rust.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Door) : 11-13 F1 Grenades , or 2 explosive charges (usually taking two due to decay)

---

Now its pretty obvious that a metal doorway + metal door provide better protection that a wooden doorway + wooden door. But what if you do a wooden doorway + metal door, or metal doorway + wooden door. Does this affect its resistance in any way, or does it take the resistance of a specific item, or does it take the resistance of the strongest item?

---

So basically what I've learned is that a wall-section (window, door, wall, etc.) is as strong as the weakest part of the section. So for example if you build metal window bars and place them in a wooden window (frame), the section would be as strong as the wooden window since that is the weakest link. So to return to my original question, let's say we place a metal door in a wooden doorway (which happens quite often), would you be able to blow up the wooden doorway without destroying the metal door? If so, would destroying the wooden doorway grant you access to the base (or building/wall/etc)? The same could be asked for a window.

Answer (score 2):

The wooden door would have the same health in a metal doorway as it would a wooden one, taking only a single charge or numerous attacks from various equipment to break. Each individual item's health is its own health, completely unaffected by its surroundings.

Destroying an object that is supporting another object will cause the supported object to be destroyed as well. A door cannot be placed without a doorway, a doorway/wall cannot be placed without 2 connecting pillars, window bars need windows and so on. Destroying something that would render the conjoined objects unsupported will destroy them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a metal door can be placed in a wooden doorway. I'm doing this all the time since i haven't got the metal doorway researched yet. Is this a 'as strong as the weakest link' kind of thing then?

Comment: No, each item has a set amount of health that does not change when placed in different situations.

Comment: Are metal doorways better than wooden doorways in any way, then?

Comment: I've added another part to my question to get this question to a practical use.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research on this subject as well and found that there are some guides on steam explaining what it takes to destroy several items with different types of weapons. 
Below I have quoted one such guide explaining the subject. It doesn't matter what type of door you place in a doorway as it strengthens the same whatsoever.

[source](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=220007432)

> Wood Window: 11-12 - Grenades, 1 Charge - C4  
>  Wood Window w/
>   Bars: 2 Charges - C4  
>  Wood Doorway: 11-12 - Grenades, 1-2
>   Charges - C4  
>  Wood Doorway w/Door Attached: 2 Charges - C4 
>   
>  Wood Door: 200 Hits - Metal Hatchet, 84 Hits - Pickaxe, 6 -
>   Grenades, 1 Charge - C4  
>  Metal Window: 2 Charges - C4  
>   Metal Window w/Bars: 2 Charges - C4  
>  Metal Doorway: 2 Charges -
>   C4  
>  Metal Doorway w/Door Attached: 3 Charges - C4  
>  Metal
>   Door: 11 - Grenades, 2 Charges - C4 (Metal Doors cannot be damaged by
>   melee weapons or guns. Only through explosives.)

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not. Could you read the question again?

Comment: Actually it does, I'm quoting my answer above now, "Wood Window: 11-12 - Grenades, 1 Charge - C4
Wood Window w/ Bars: 2 Charges - C4
Wood Doorway: 11-12 - Grenades, 1-2 Charges - C4
Wood Doorway w/Door Attached: 2 Charges - C4
Metal Window: 2 Charges - C4
Metal Window w/Bars: 2 Charges - C4
Metal Doorway: 2 Charges - C4
Metal Doorway w/Door Attached: 3 Charges - C4"
as far as doors go, it doesn't matter what type of door you put in a doorway the doorway strengthens as soon as there is a door in it.

Comment: Ok so an advantage of using a metal door instead of a wooden door is the fact that a metal door can't be destroyed by melee weapons (only by explosives). What is the advantage of using a metal doorway then?